# Sublime Text 3 and Anaconda / SublimeCodeIntel Autocompletion

Tags: python, anaconda, sublimetext3

I just switched over from PyCharm to ST3 for Python development. I've installed Anaconda for autocompletion (and I've also tried SublimeCodeIntel).  Here is the issue that I have having. If I type in the following

```
import numpy as np
```

both packages suggest 'numpy' after the 'as' and, if I am not paying attention, when I hit enter, the statement is now changed to this:

```
import numpy as numpy
```

This also happens with say

```
import pandas as pd
```

which becomes

```
import pandas as pandas
```

Is there a way to change this behavior? For now, I have to remember to hit space so that my statements remain as I type this. This behavior is annoying and I have not experienced this with any other editor (PyCharm, Spyder.)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> to auto-complete instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>, set the `"auto_complete_commit_on_tab"` preference to `true`.

For those who aren't familiar with Sublime Text 3, [add it to Preferences.sublime-settings](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/settings.html):

```js
{
    "auto_complete_commit_on_tab": true,
    // your other settings...
}
```